# Rails Paths Questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question involving Rails paths.

If I wanted to access the index method of the products path, I would use products_path.

Now, if the method was called search, what would the corresponding path be?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to run `$rake routes` to see paths you can use (based on your `config/routes.rb` of course), it's really handy.